# How to loop over tokens from a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Say I have a string - `'9999,34244324324\n88888,131321323\n77777,8787223'`,

I want each comma separated number from each pair separated by `\n` to be inserted into two columns in a table.

For example, like below:

```
9999 |34244324324
88888|131321323
77777|8787223
```

With REGEXP_SUBSTR, I am able to get the pairs together:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '((\d+),(\d+)\n?)',1,i, null, j)
```

where `i` find the `num,num` match and `j` is 1 or 2 for first or second number.

I can imagine looping this `i` times which I can get from `REGXP_COUNT` but that seems like repeating same thing `n` times. What is the proper way to achieve this?

I am doing DB script after a long time so don't remember exactly though I have done this earlier. So I need suggestions on this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Split whole string into rows by "\n" as a delimiter:

```sql
select *
from  xmltable(
      'tokenize(., "\\n")'
      passing '9999,34244324324\n88888,131321323\n77777,8787223' 
      columns
         s varchar2(100) path '.'
      )
```

Result:

```
S
---------------------
9999,34244324324
88888,131321323
77777,8787223
```

2. Split each line into substrings by "," as a delimiter:
   2.1 using regexp_substr:

```sql
select 
  s,
  regexp_substr(s,'^([^,]*),([^,]*)',1,1,'',1)  s1,
  regexp_substr(s,'^([^,]*),([^,]*)',1,1,'',2)  s2
from  xmltable(
      'tokenize(., "\\n")'
      passing '9999,34244324324\n88888,131321323\n77777,8787223' 
      columns
         s varchar2(100) path '.'
      )
```

Result:

```
S                    S1           S2
-------------------- ------------ ------------
9999,34244324324     9999         34244324324
88888,131321323      88888        131321323
77777,8787223        77777        8787223
```

or 2.2 using the same xmltable:

```sql
select *
from  xmltable(
      'for $r in tokenize(., "\\n")
         return element R {
            attribute s1 {tokenize($r, ",")[1]}, 
            attribute s2 {tokenize($r, ",")[2]}
         }'
      passing '9999,34244324324\n88888,131321323\n77777,8787223' 
      columns
         s1 varchar2(10) path '@s1',
         s2 varchar2(10) path '@s2'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure regexp_substr based solution.  The "d" sub-query is purely your data.  Oracle does not understand \n well so chr(10) takes care of that.  The lines sub-query splits your data into rows by new-line.  The last query splits apart the string at commas.  You can expand beyond two columns of comma separated data by just adding additional instances of regexp_substr and incrementing the last (position) parameter.

```
WITH d AS
 (SELECT REPLACE('9999,34244324324\n88888,131321323\n77777,8787223',
                 '\n',
                 chr(10)) AS ata
    FROM dual),
lines AS
 (SELECT regexp_substr(d.ata,
                       '[^' || chr(10) || ']+',
                       1,
                       LEVEL) AS line
    FROM d
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(d.ata,
                           '[^' || chr(10) || ']+',
                           1,
                           LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT l.line,
       regexp_substr(l.line,
                     '[^,]+',
                     1,
                     1) AS c1,
       regexp_substr(l.line,
                     '[^,]+',
                     1,
                     2) AS c2
  FROM lines l;
```

Produces:

```
line                c1      c2
----------------    -----   -----------
9999,34244324324    9999    34244324324
88888,131321323     88888   131321323
77777,8787223       77777   8787223
```